# Using partial integral to show $ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{x^2 e^x}{(1+e^x)^2}dx = 4\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{x e^{-x}}{(1+e^{-x})}dx $

Tags: integration

I'm getting the variance of logistic distribution.

For acquiring the expectation of squares, I need to show this :

$$ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{x^2 e^x}{(1+e^x)^2}dx = 4\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{x e^{-x}}{(1+e^{-x})}dx $$

I know that these are symmetric for $x=0$, so it would be

$$ 2\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{x^2 e^{-x}}{(1+e^{-x})^2}dx $$

But the problem is going to start. I fancy to show that this is equivalent to

$$ 4\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{x e^{-x}}{(1+e^{-x})}dx $$

When I tried to use the partial integral, I set

$$ f = x^2, f' = 2x, g' = \frac{e^{-x}}{(1+e^{-x})^2},   g = \frac{1}{(1+e^{-x})} $$

but with this, I couldn't make that form.

I want only those form, otherwise I can find easily web searching but that's are not I want to find.

Thank you for all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note

\begin{align}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{x^2 e^x}{(1+e^x)^2}dx
&=2\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{x^2 e^{x}}{(1+e^{x})^2}dx= 
- 2\int_{0}^{\infty} x^2d\left(\frac{1}{1+e^{x}}\right)\\
&=-\frac{2x^2}{1+e^{x}}\bigg|_0^\infty+ 2\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{2x}{1+e^{x}}dx
= 4\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{xe^{-x}}{1+e^{-x}}dx
\end{align}

Comment: Many thanks of you!!! I tried from $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{x^2 e^{-x}}{(1+e^{-x})^2}$. But that was divergent. Very little but equivalent start results somewhat different circumstance! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

First note that
$$
4\frac{{xe^{ - x} }}{{1 + e^{ - x} }} = 4\frac{x}{{1 + e^x }}.
$$
Now
$$
\left[ {2\frac{{x^2 }}{{1 + e^x }}} \right]^\prime   = 4\frac{x}{{1 + e^x }} - 2\frac{{x^2 e^x }}{{(1 + e^x )^2 }}.
$$
Integrating both sides gives
$$
0 = 4\int_0^{ + \infty } {\frac{x}{{1 + e^x }}dx}  - 2\int_0^{ + \infty } {\frac{{x^2 e^x }}{{(1 + e^x )^2 }}dx} ,
$$
that is
$$
4\int_0^{ + \infty } {\frac{x}{{1 + e^x }}dx}  = 2\int_0^{ + \infty } {\frac{{x^2 e^x }}{{(1 + e^x )^2 }}dx}  = \int_{ - \infty }^{ + \infty } {\frac{{x^2 e^x }}{{(1 + e^x )^2 }}dx} .
$$

Comment: Starting from the result! Why did I can't think of that? So brillient idea, thank you so much!